# Webpack file-loader, стоит ли добавлять картинки модулями?

Tags: webpack

Мне не понятно зачем добавлять изображения модулями в приложение через file-loader, это же влияет на размер сборки, когда это имеет смысл, почему бы просто не грузить изображения отдельными запросами?

Comment: На отдельный запрос-ответ может уходить дополнительное время до 100-200 миллисекунд (а при плохом интернете ещё больше)

Comment: Для множества мелких изображений это более важно, чем для скриптов и стилей. Для этих целей также используют [CSS-спрайты](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-sprite), но вебпак сильно упрощает задачу.